# ' ' is incompatible with attribute icon (attr) reference. error: failed processing manifest

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, gradle, android-manifest

```
packaged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:26: error: ' ' is incompatible with attribute icon (attr) reference.
error: failed processing manifest.
```

[image][image]

In android manifest file line number 26 shows some error.

Answer (score 3):

Removing `android:icon=" "` on line 18 should do the trick

You can [refer here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element) for other parameters that can be used with activity tag

Also view, android:icon needs drawable resource